# Data Class Context is required is ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core

I am having an issue with creating views where context class / model class is required, since the viewmodel isn't an entity this doesn't work and I don't have time to create from scratch without a template.

Please note that model class is required after selecting template and it shouldn't be, went through many searches and didn't find an answer .

Please advise if you faced and solved the issue before.

PS  I am only facing this issue with 1 project only, others don't have it.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you select any action like Create, Edit, Delete or List? You are required to specific which ViewModel it will used for generating views. If empty is selected, it is not required to have ViewModel. Please post more details about it.

Comment: With DbContext you will always use your Model class (Entity) and you can map it to your ViewModel. Now the easiest option will be to use Automapper for mapping your Model class to your ViewModel.

Comment: You don't want to assign the value of the model to the viewmodel every time?You can try Automapper, and what does 'since the viewmodel isn't an entity this doesn't work and I don't have time to create from scratch without a template.' mean?